# Can I set DataGridHeader by AutoGeneratedColumns?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want set header FirstName,LastName by AutoGeneratedColumns.
I tried this code, but DataGrid Header display Name1,Name2.

I know, DataGridColumns can make header.
but I want set header by AutoGeneratedColumns.

Is there anything way?

Thank you for taking the time review for this!

ViewModel

```
public class DataGridItems
{
    [Description("FirstName")]
    public string Name1 { get; set; }

    [Description("LastName")]
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
}
```

MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<DataGridItems> ItemsSource { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(a => new DataGridItems { Name1 = a.ToString(), Name2 = "Last" + a.ToString() });
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please avoid placing tags in your question title (see tagging help page for more information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event in the view:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<DataGridItems> ItemsSource { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(a => new DataGridItems { Name1 = a.ToString(), Name2 = "Last" + a.ToString() });
    }


    private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        DescriptionAttribute descriptionAttribute = typeof(DataGridItems)
            .GetProperty(e.PropertyName)?
            .GetCustomAttributes(true)?
            .OfType<DescriptionAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (descriptionAttribute != null)
            e.Column.Header = descriptionAttribute.Description;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"/>
```

It's is not the responsibility of the view model to provide functionality to set the headers of a `DataGrid` in the view. This should be implemented in the view or the control, much like when you set the headers to some fixed values in the XAML markup.